# Settlers Cities and Knights + Fish: Cost of a commodity

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, catan-traders-and-barbarians

When using fish, the card states that 4 fish are used to buy a resource.  What is the cost, in fish, of a commodity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot buy commodities using fish.

http://download.catan.com/en/download/?combination-Fishermen_Cities-and-Knights.pdf

> - If you discard 3 fish, you may draw one card from the hand of one of your opponents  (Resource or Commodity Card).
> - If you discard 4 fish, you may take resource card but not a commodity.
> - The following applies also for the combination with Cities & Knights: Fish are no resources  – and no commodities. This implies
>     that fish are never affected by Progress Cards,  particularly not by
>     the yellow Progress Cards.

Comment: TY for your answer.